# Changing Error Message in Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, paperclip-validation

I have a Rails (3.1) app with a model validation that, when triggered, puts the model and field name before the message, e.g.:

> Profile image profile image content type Only jpeg, gif and png files are allowed for profile pictures

Is there a way to avoid that, so it reads:

> Only jpeg, gif and png files are allowed for profile pictures

model.rb validation:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :profile_image,
  :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'],
  :message      => "Only jpeg, gif and png files are allowed for profile pictures"
```

The error appears as a part of this code in my layout:

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div class="alert alert-message error" data-alert="alert">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
    <ul>
      <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please show us the code for your view where this error is shown.

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that `msg` is not actually the message but the entire error hash, and so calling `<%= msg %>` actually converts the whole hash to a string, including the keys. You could confirm this with `<%= msg.class %>`.

Assuming the view code you posted is a partial it would be helpful to see the view that includes the partial. If it's not a partial it would be useful to see the surrounding code.

Comment: Sorry, I added the entire partial now

Comment: Oh, so you're passing the error in `flash`. How is it being set in your controller? Did you confirm what kind of object `msg` is? `msg.inspect` would be useful as well.

Comment: sorry, i was looking at the incorrect partial (fixed my description).  i found out when i put the commands you mentioned.  with those, it returns: ActiveModel::Errors and #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x813c960>